# Why it still works without installing AndroidInjectionModule?

Tags: dagger-2

According to [Dagger documentation about injecting activity objects](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html#injecting-activity-objects), it says that installing `AndroidInjectionModule` in your application component. However, everything is fine without it.

Does it means that I don't need to declare it?  Under what circumstances will it be wrong?

For example:
Injected instance

```
data class Food(val name: String)
```

Module

```
@Module
class FoodModule{
    @Provides
    fun provideFood(): Food {
        return Food("cholocate")
    }
}
```

BindingModule

```
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FoodModule::class])
    abstract fun FoodShop(): MainActivity
}
```

AppComponent (Without installing AndroidInjectionModule)

```
@Component(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
interface AppComponent{
    fun inject(app: App)
}
```

App

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingActivityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return dispatchingActivityInjector
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var food: Food

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.d("test", "Get ${food.name}")
    }
}
```

It get chocolate successfully in MainActivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it means that I don't need to declare it? Under what circumstances will it be wrong?

It actually seems like you don't need to declare it, but it might lead to compile errors if you don't.

---

If you have a look at [AndroidInjectionModule](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/6a26bf02e7ad98a6969944c4a2ae81299122068b/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjectionModule.java) you can see that it just lists a bunch of `@Multibinds` methods for framework types.

```
@Multibinds
abstract Map<Class<? extends Activity>, AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>>
    activityInjectorFactories();
```

Now if you look up [Declaring `@Multibinds`](https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html#declaring-multibindings) you can read that

> You do not have to use `@Multibinds` for sets or maps that have at least one `@IntoSet`, `@ElementsIntoSet`, or `@IntoMap` binding, but you do have to declare them if they may be empty.

And to *declare them if they may be empty* is exactly what the `AndroidInjectionModule` module is doing for you. If the Android Injection parts would require an undefined Map of injector factories you would probably get a compile time error stating that it cannot be provided.

The reason that you don't need the module is because you're using `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, of which the generated code will contain a `@Binds @IntoMap etc.` method, that declares the bindings map. Stated above—as it is not empty anymore—you would not need the additional `@Multibinds` declaration that `AndroidInjectionModule` provides for the non-empty multibinding.

---

You might not *need* the module, but it will declare all the framework injector factories for you in case that they might be empty, possibly preventing one or two compile errors. After all the javadoc simply states that it [*should*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) be installed, not that it *must*.

> This module should be installed in the component that is used to inject the Application class.

Comment: Thanks for your expiation. Would you mind giving a example that the use of requiring an undefined Map? Or, it just for preventing compile error?

Comment: @Mumi It really depends on your use case. If you want Dagger to provide a list of items and that list of items can be empty in some cases, then you should use it to declare the list, to prevent potential errors. Or you might add it to your module for documentation purposes.